# WMS Layer color scale

Tags: raster, geoserver, leaflet, wms

I would like to use color scale of my raster data in my leaflet web application exactly same way as it is in this video https://youtu.be/l47ABvDLiq8?t=51s .

Does somebody know which service is used for raster data publishing? Is it basic geoserver? Or is there used some another wms service?

Comment: What makes you think it is a WMS at all?

Comment: it is a tiled map so maybe WMS but nothing to show one way or the other. Could certainly be done using GeoServer

Comment: It is web service, tiled, that's what makes me think, it's wms. Do you have some idea, how to get something as it's in the video ?

Comment: By "exactly same way as the video", do you mean also that you have multispectral raster data?

Comment: Yes, I mean multispectral raster.

Comment: Looking at the MicaSense Atlas example from https://www.micasense.com/atlas/ I'm not sure if any WMS is used to provide the data.  The changing of the colours can be done in the canvas JavaScript and doesn't need any service.

Comment: I know Micasense atlas. it's workflow works, that server sends the colored data according the min and max value which are defined in the request pointing to wms server. So it's done on the server. Can you please tell me which JS lib to use for cahnging the canvas ? Thanks